# Error when trying to upload multiple files to S3 using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am working on a project to be able to upload files to an `Amazon S3 bucket` from a website using PHP.

However, I am hitting an issue where it comes with the following error:

> fopen(uploadDoc/1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

I am looping through the multiple files to upload them individually like so:

```
if (isset($_FILES['files']))
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
        if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]))
        {
            $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $ext = explode('.', $name);
            $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
            if ($ext == 'zip') { $temp_file_path = "uploadZip/{$name}"; $s3Key = "zip"; }
            else { $temp_file_path = "uploadDoc/{$name}"; $s3Key = "docs"; }
            try
            {
                $body = fopen($temp_file_path, 'rb');
                $s3->putObject([
                    'Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET,
                    'Key' => "{$s3Key}/{$name}",
                    'Body' => $body,
                    'ACL' => "public-read"
                ]);
            }
            catch (S3Exception $e)
            {
                die('There was an error uploading ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
            fclose($body);
            unlink($temp_file_path);
        }
    }
}
```

When I have tried to upload a single file using the same code but not in a loop, it works fine, so I am really confused.

Below is the form being used to upload the files:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]"><br>
            <input name="upload" type="submit" value="Upload" class="general-btn blue">
        </form>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that I have made some errors in my code.

Firstly, I have missed one line of code from within the PHP code snippet provided above, this is:

```
if ($ext == 'zip') { $temp_file_path = "uploadZip/{$tmp_file_name}"; $s3Key = "zip"; }
else { $temp_file_path = "uploadDoc/{$tmp_file_name}"; $s3Key = "docs"; }
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $temp_file_path);
try
```

The second error made was within the HTML code snippet above, which was giving all the inputs the same file ID, by changing the IDs to have a different ID the files upload successfully with no errors

Thanks